# Routing parameter pass as 'text/box' as requirement pass in routing.yml in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

```
stockregister_report_itemcode:
    pattern:  /stockregister/{itemcode}/{category}/report/{subcategory}/{openingbalance}/{type}/{actunit}
    defaults: { _controller: "EduAssetBundle:StockRegister:stockregisterItemcodeReport" }
    requirements:
        itemcode: .+
        category: .+
        subcategory: .+
        openingbalance: .+
        type: .+
        actunit: .+
```

Here i pass the {actunit} as 'box/packet' its split values parameter not working

Answer (score 0):

All you parameter have pattern `.+`, it is greedy. So the first possible parameter catches max possible part of url.
Change pattern for all parameters to `.+?` or specify in patterns what exactly characters parameter can contain (ex: `[a-z0-9]+`)

Comment: Not Working it display route not found

Comment: and what is full url?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities why it may not work (any or even both):

1). You forgot to specify the HTTP verb (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc.).

2). Since the `/` character is used to separate route elements, you should encode the value when passing it. Therefore use `box%2Fpacket` instead of `box/packet`.